# Crash when debug in Iphone Simulator

Tags: xcode, crash, ios-simulator

Have forgot when it started from,when I debug My on Iphone Simulator,Xcode4 will crash.
just when the Simulator is  opening.I have uninstall it for many times, but the same result.why? I have been crasy with all the crashs,more intolerable, my debug error is disappeared.what cause that?anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode->preference->general->Reset "Don't Ask Me" Warnings

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen only with one specific project or all your projects. If it is one project then that project has an error causing the crash. If it is all projects then it is a xcode problem. Where are you trying to install it from? Try doing this, open up terminal and enter in

```
sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

This will uninstall xcode all the way. Then try installing the xcode again after downlading it from developer.apple.com if you have a developer account or buying it from the Mac App Store. Hope this helps.